# Radar/spider chart in iOS?

Tags: ios, charts, radar-chart, ios-charts

Is there any easy way to create radar chart like this one please?

[image]

I found a very nice and useful library called [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts), but I can't seem to find a way to change the hexagon look they use for radar view with this circles that I need.

Also, it looks like you cant use [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) with pods for project supporting lower platforms than ios 8.0, which is a bit of a problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, I am using ios-charts on iOS 7. You just need to use source files for ios 7.0.

Towards radar chart, you want arc line rather than straight line, you can override `drawWeb` to draw the webs with arc.

What you could do is replacing `CGContextStrokeLineSegments` with your custom `CGContextAddArcToPoint` properly